# How to add item to Favorites *silently*?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

in the Gnome desktop, I know how to create a desktop entry for a custom program.  I also know how to pin it to my Favorites by right clicking and selecting Add to Favorites.  I want to do that last step in silent mode, from a shell script as part of a larger automation process.  Is this possible?

Comment: What are these favorites? Is it something from a graphical file browser? Which one?

Comment: Gnome desktop (not file browser), sorry for not clarifying, I specified the Gnome tag but not in the post.  I'll update the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Do a check
desktop-file-validate ${HOME}/.local/share/applications/*.desktop

# List apps pinned to dock
gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps

# Pin new list to dock after editing
gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "['doublecmd.desktop', 'textadept.desktop', 'notherapp.desktop', 'okular.desktop']"
```